# Adding columns in a React-bootstrap Carousel but unable to get different images in each column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using React-bootstrap Carousel and have used React-bootstrap's grid system to create multiple columns in a slide and I want to dynamically add different images to the columns and once the columns are filled if there are other images I want it to automatically create new slide but the problem is it is using same image in all the columns in one slide and then creating a new slide for the next image

This is my code

```
    const data = [
    {
      image:
        "https://d25u15mvjkult8.cloudfront.net/videos/7265406/images/500/dOlh05avp978ye6iGOid.jpg",
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      image:
        "https://d25u15mvjkult8.cloudfront.net/videos/7265203/images/500/955tjRfCGzpQyNZM3Kiz.jpg",
      id: 2,
    },
    {
      image:
        "https://d25u15mvjkult8.cloudfront.net/videos/7261533/images/500/PBHl35kwCbsoO27St6tP.jpg",
      id: 3,
    },
    {
      image:
        "https://loco.gg/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.easyvideo.in%2Fdefault_thumb%2F8561b9c2-a40a-4404-8c41-c54d54c50e4b.jpg&w=750&q=50",
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      image:
        "https://loco.gg/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.easyvideo.in%2Fstream_thumb%2F3bf4ad93-ad8e-4a55-be1d-c8e5504a55ff.jpg&w=750&q=50",
      id: 2,
    },
    {
      image:
        "https://loco.gg/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.easyvideo.in%2Fdefault_thumb%2F10e9c507-bd06-4a39-bb2d-f3a21ae0fe6a.jpg&w=750&q=50",
      id: 3,
    },
  ];



<Carousel className="gh78">
  {data.map((item, index) => (
    <Carousel.Item key={index}>
      <a>
        <div className="trenvid23">
          <Row>
            <Col md={8}>
              <div>
                <img src={item.image} alt="terndingimage"></img>
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col md={4}>
              <div>
                <Col md={12}>
                  <img src={item.image} alt="terndingimage"></img>
                </Col>
                <Col md={12}>
                  <img src={item.image}></img>
                </Col>
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
      </a>
    </Carousel.Item>
  ))}
</Carousel>
```

This is the output I am getting[image]

[image]

But I want different images in each columns and a new slide to be created only after the 3  columns have been filled and there are more images

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
    {
      image:"URL1",
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      image:"URL2",
      id: 2,
    },
    {
      image:"URL3",
      id: 3,
    },
{
      image:"URL4",
      id: 4,
    }]
  return (
     <div className='grid sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 pt-6 gap-10'>
{
data.map(myData=><(Component Name)
key={data._id}
myData={myData}></(Component Name)>)
}
```

Use different IDs in the array of your data.
I mapped the data array and pass the value to another component which will be displayed in the grid[css is tailwind here].